# Reddit API for voting

Tags: java, api, reddit

I'm able to login to reddit via the API with Java, but I can't get a vote to process. This was an attempt to do a reduced case just to get it to work. But all I get back is "User is required to do this"; any ideas?

```
String apiParams = "api_type=json&id=c38ghjg&dir=1&uh=" + modHash;

URL voteURL = new URL("http://www.reddit.com/api/vote");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) voteURL.openConnection ();
connection.setDoOutput (true);
connection.setRequestMethod ("POST");
connection.setUseCaches (false);
connection.setRequestProperty ("Content-Type",
                            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" );
connection.setRequestProperty("cookie", "reddit_session="+cookie);
connection.setRequestProperty ("Content-Length",
                            String.valueOf( apiParams.length() ));
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
wr.writeBytes( apiParams );
wr.flush();
wr.close();
InputStream cis = connection.getInputStream();

HashMap<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String,String> ();

if(cis != null){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper ();

    TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>
    mapReference = new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>> () { };

    Map<String, Object> resultJSON = mapper.readValue (cis, mapReference);

    Map<String, Object> json = (Map<String, Object>) resultJSON.get ("json");
    Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String,Object>) json.get ("data");
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

Comment: @Voo there is an API, though - maybe they support site APIs for e.g. mobile apps to use. Won't the next version of the SO API support voting? You need to be an authenticated user to vote, which is the `modHash` value at the top. Fred, are you sure the modhash is correct?

Comment: @Rup yeah I pulled it out to post here, but its from the header,and I believe correct.

Comment: Voting robots? Next they will want [driver's liscenses](http://www.nytimes.com/2010/10/10/science/10google.html?pagewanted=all). We can't have that!

Answer (score 3):

Did you set the reddit_session cookie first?  You have to do that before you access features like voting.  (You must get the cookie through the login json.)